# “Ionic cordova emulate android --consolelogs” not reloading and not showing console logs

Tags: angular, cordova, android-emulator, adb, ionic3

Good afternoon,

Suddenly, my development environment stopped making livereload and showing console logs on my android emulator.

The app is emulated and performing well but I can’t update the code without having to restart the emulator neither debugging through console logs.
I searched all over the internet and tried almost everything I found but nothing seems to work. Some things that I tried:

- Wipe Data from emulator
- Reset ADB (Kill -> Start)
- Remove and Add platform

  ```
  ionic cordova platform rm android
  ionic cordova platform add android
  ```
- Ran analysis tools

  ```
  cordova requirements
  ionic doctor check
  ```
- Other commands I also tried:

  ```
  npm install -g ionic@latest
  npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
  npm install ionic-angular@latest –save
  npm install --save-dev --save-exact ionic@latest
  ```

---

> Environment details

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

Local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools: 26.1.1
Node : v6.11.3
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 7
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: what does it do? the command stops when app is loaded?

Comment: Did you try with `-c` instead of `--consolelogs `?